# Pin DBI tool - Create executable

Tags: dynamic-analysis, instrumentation, pintool, intel

I'm starting to learn Intel's Pin framework and I can't figure out if it's possible to create an executable.

I mean, rather than creating a module and forcing people to download Pin + the module, is it possible to directly create a tool (executable)?

Comment: what do you mean by "creating an executable"? Also what do you mean by module? read this manual for more information on how it works - https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/97619/Pin/html/index.html

Comment: I tried to dev a little program based on ManualExamples. To use it I have to do something like : `pin -t ./my_module.so -- ./test`. What I'd like to know is if it's possible to compile it as a standalone. Rather than giving my "my_module.so" I'd like just create a binary that way people won't have to download Pin and module, only my binary to use it.

Comment: "pin" is a instrumentation framework "./my_module.so" is a "pintool" which is used to add instrumentation. "./test" is a binary under examination. "pin" can't work without "pintool". If you don't want to add instrumentation, then you can provide a blank "pintool" (without any calls to instrumentation routines, just the main function). If you want to remove "pintool" then your pin framework will be purposeless.